# Can't access array of type PFObject with includekey Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a `PFQuery` with `includeKey` and then I pass the object to an array named 'queryArray'. In the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm trying to access the array without success.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class OrdensCompraTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var queryArray: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Transacao")
    query.includeKey("pointerUser")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) pedidos.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                self.queryArray = objects     
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> OrdensCompraTableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OrdensCompraCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrdensCompraTableViewCell

    println(queryArray)

 //     let transacao = queryArray[indexPath.row] as PFObject

 //   cell.tituloCecula.text = transacao.objectForKey("objectId") as! String

 //  var ola = transacao.relationForKey("pointerUser.username")
//println( transacao.objectForKey("aceite"))

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `includeKey` can confuse people. Make sure objects isn't return nil in the call back before passing it to `self.queryArray`

Comment: I have done a println with "objects" and it returns the objects OK.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually reload the tableview after the Parse data comes in.  Also your numberOfRowsInSection is hard coded which is why the tableView thinks there is data in the array when there is not.

```
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

            self.queryArray = objects
            // RELOAD TABLEVIEW
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
```

And To fix the number of rows in section you should return self.queryData.count

Comment: Yes, but thats not the problem. I can hard code 1 row just to test... Because there is 1 row in the query. :)

Comment: If you add break points, you will see that you are returning 1 row and the tableview is trying to access the array before the query finished.  You are making a network connection which takes time to complete, try what I told you before claiming it is not the problem.

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. I've made the changes, how can I access now the related object? ["pointerUser"]["username"]?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if your going to add your parse objects to an array, you should add it to an *array*:

```
 var queryArray:NSMutableArray = []

 override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.queryArray = NSMutableArray()

    ..findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
          for object in objects {
               self.queryArray.addObject(object)
               //reload UI components
          }
```

Then your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should always reflect the number in that array :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.queryArray.count
}
```

Comment: That gives me an error " '[PFObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line method should return the **self.queryArray.count***

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

And your forgot to **reloadData()** after you assign the query data to your array of PFObject

And cellForRowAtPath you need to assign the cell object to the array of data at each indexPath.row